# HTML email confirmations - can I us js or php within the email?

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I created an html email confirmation that gets sent to people who fill out my order form.
In the Shipping Address fields of the email I want it to show either: the separate shipping address they entered OR the same info from their billing address IF they didn't enter separate shipping info. This is what I have done:

```
<td><?php
     $txt = false;
     if( file_exists( 'text46' ) )
        $txt = file_get_contents( 'text46' );
     else if ( file_!exists( 'text46' ) )
        $txt = file_get_contents( 'text12' );
     ?>
</td>
```

Dont' laugh. I got this code from somewhere else and it looked like the closet thing I've seen that could work (but it doesn't). But I have NO idea what some of it means. Like: should $txt=false?

I don't know. I just need this table data in the email to show 'text46' (the shipping address) if it was entered on the form, and if it wasn't then I want the table data to show 'text12' (the billing address). Can this even be done in the actual email?

I'm a MAJOR beginner and I know what I want it to do, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: PHP yes, javascript no.

Comment: `$txt` is a variable. `$txt=false` you are setting the variable to boolean false.

Comment: You can certainly generate the HTML of the email using php scripts.  Note that file_!exists is an error.

Comment: James, yeah I was trying to convey that if text46 did NOT exist then use text12. But I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: If you have a PHP server, then you can use PHP BEFORE you generate the email and send it to your SMTP server.  A few things however: "else if (file_!exists('text46'))" should be changed to "else if (!file_exists('text46'))" and you should move your "text46" files outside of your root directory (right now, anyone looking at your website can read "text46" as a plain text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** put code inside an e-mail and expect that it will work because of some simple reasons:

1. When people receive your e-mail, the service that handles it automatically blocks any code inside of it from being executed. So javascript will not work, PHP neither, and so on. It would be a huge security flaw if this could be possible.
2. PHP will never work anyway because is a server-side language. This means that it can't be executed on your pc. It needs to be executed on a server that sends a response back when finished.

Lear more about what server-side means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting

Comment: I figured your #1 was the case. But on your #2, this email is constructed and the table data is collected on the server side and the resulting email is sent out. Every table cell in the email calls for the results that are input on the form. How do I get one cell to call either "this" result or "that" result?

Comment: Assuming that an user sent a form data containing the variable `shipping_address`, than you will do: `if ($_POST["shipping_address"]) echo $_POST["shipping_address"];`. If the user hasn't inserted that variable you can do `else if ($_POST["billing_address"]) echo $_POST["billing_address"];` and if no value was sent then add another `else` like this: `else echo "Error, no address found.";` or something similar.

Comment: That looks like what I want. What do I add before and after that? php or script tags? I literally need the whole snippet since I am so new.

Comment: Oh, and do I put that inside the <td></td>?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you write: `echo "<td>";` then all the code I said above, and at the end: `echo "</td>";`.

Comment: Well, that didn't work. It showed all of the code in the email. There's something I'm missing or not understanding. 
It's seeming like I should put this code at the top of the page and give my table cell a div id or something so only the result comes out in the table cell. I don't know. I hate to keep bothering you with it when I am such a beginner. I'm trying though.

Comment: I can't help you more than this because I don't know your php code or what you are doing or what element are involved... I'm sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
Need to let everyone know that I found a solution. Instead of putting anything IN the email that would get ignored by email clients, I found some code that would auto-fill the Shipping fields on my form if a box was checked. Then I get the results in the email like I wanted.

I could have done this months ago if I had known to ask if emails would even work with scripts in them. Your answers helped me look for a different way to get the overall job done.

Thanks for all the help guys!

Here is the code I used for the auto-fill and the check box:`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetShipping(checked) {
    if (checked) {
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem46_text_1").value = document.getElementById("item12_text_1").value;
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem47_text_1").value = document.getElementById("item17_text_1").value; 
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem48_text_1").value = document.getElementById("item14_text_1").value; 
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem49_select_1").value = document.getElementById("item15_select_1").value; 
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem50_text_1").value = document.getElementById("item51_text_1").value; 
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem52_text_1").value = document.getElementById("item18_text_1").value; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem46_text_1").value = ''; 
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem47_text_1").value = ''; 
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem48_text_1").value = ''; 
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem49_select_1").value = '';
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem50_text_1").value = ''; 
        document.getElementById("Shippingitem52_text_1").value = ''; 
    }
}
</script>


<div class="fb-checkbox" style="color: rgb(168, 28, 45); font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px;">
          <input type="checkbox" onclick="SetShipping(this.checked);"/>Check Box to copy info to Shipping.
        </div>`
```